# Why is my jax-ws client writing error messages to stdout?

Tags: soap, weblogic, jax-ws

I have a jax-ws client which is writing error messages to stdout instead of log file when some server side exception is thrown from weblogic server.

The following is the message
   Executing  /SunOS/sparcv9/packages/jdk/jdk1.8.0_221/bin/java idg.pdg -status pending

> Mar 04, 2020 4:13:56 AM weblogic.wsee.WseeCoreMessages
>   errorLogException SEVERE: Error while invoking endpoint
>   http://xxx.xyz.com:9502/xmlpserver/services/v2/ScheduleService from
>   client; ServiceName:
>   {http://xmlns.oracle.com/oxp/service/v2}ScheduleService ; PortName:
>   {http://xmlns.oracle.com/oxp/service/v2}ScheduleService ; Client side
>   features: [weblogic.jws.jaxws.client.ClientIdentityFeature]; Client
>   side policies:

How to make app to log messages to logfile?

Comment: Are you using any SLF4J implementation (like Logback)? If so, you can route these logging statements using the [jul-to-slf4j bridge](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html#jul-to-slf4j)